# How to render clean html in Storybook 6 docs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markdown, storybook

I'm using Storybook to document some html components.

However, in order to create a story in mdx I have to use the `Story` component, meaning I can't use raw html and instead have to return my markup as a string:

```js
import { Story } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';

<Story name="Simple Button">
   {`<button class="my-button">Download Now</button>`}
</Story>
```

Which renders the source code as a string:

[image]

Is there a way I can return clean markup or have the source show as true html? The source showing quotes and lack of syntax highlighting makes for poor documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that since [v6.0.0-alpha.22](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/releases/tag/v6.0.0-alpha.22) you can render any custom source code in Storybook.

Using the `Canvas` block's `params` object you can set custom source for your story.

```
import { Story, Canvas } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';

<Canvas>
  <Story name="custom source" height="100px" parameters={{ docs: { source: { code: `<button class="my-button">Download Now</button>` } } }}>
    {`<button class="my-button">Download Now</button>`}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

This renders the button in the story, and the source code uses raw HTML:

[image]